# Tax rebate on Home loan on mother's property

Tags: loans, india, home

I have got a home loan from SBI on my mother's property. she is co-signee on the the loan. Can I use EMI paid for my tax saving.

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE! Please add a country tag to this question. And to your profile, if you'd like. We have members from all over the world, and you'll get a decent answer once the tag is added.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer This is most likely a question about India with SBI denoting State Bank of India.  I would expect Dheer to provide an answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

If the property was already built and paid for; post this you have taken a "Loan against Property", you will not be able to claim any tax rebate.

If you mean that the land was on your Mother's name and you have taken a loan to build the house, you can claim rebate if you have completed the construction.